# iCloud Alternative for core data like data synchronization

Tags: core-data, synchronization, icloud

I am planning to develop an app which will use a database.
This database will need to be synchronized accross multiple devices.
I need something like iCloud + CoreData but able to work also from Android and Windows

Do you know if this magical thing exists?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if it's ok that you need to be connected (no fully offline mode) - StackMob can be of help to you.
their iOS SDK even provide CoreData interfaces, and if you don't like them - you have REST APIs

Also may be you should look at:
- Simperium (no Android SDK, only REST APIs,)
- Parse.com